# Possibility of creating a folder in the wordpress root install and installing a file there, all via plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my situation. I'm creating a plugin, which uses a 3rd party API service. If I include the file ajaxAPI.php in the plugin itself, then call it via jQuery ajax with the full url, such as http://dev.website.co/wp-content/plugins/secret-plugin/ajaxAPI.php I get a 403 error.

I realize it's my server config, but other users may have the same issue. My work around is to create a folder in the site root, place my ajax file there, and call it at that point. There will be sensitive data passed via API, so I don't want to host the ajax file on my own server, for the end users security.

Summary: How can I make ajax calls when the plugins directory returns a 403 error?

Comment: Your AJAX endpoint is a major security hole, even if your plugin is disabled, someone can still send requests to it and make changes. You should use the WP AJAX API instead, at which point your problem completely dissapears

Comment: Thank you, I'll go that route. I knew my way was horrible, but I couldn't figure out the right way, so I came here. Thank you Tom, I'll try this out.

Comment: I got it working. Thanks for the direction @Tom J Nowell. Too bad I couldn't award you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[WordPress Ajax API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)** for any kind of ajax related stuff.

For more details : http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins